# Add an Event to Expo Calendar?

Tags: react-native, expo-calendar

I'm trying to add an event using `Expo Calendar` but i'm getting an error. When i call my function `openActionSheet` the `catch` block is executed and getting the `Alert` with the message `Error getting device calendars.`. When i'm consoling the error i'm getting `undefined is not a function (near '...showActionSheetWithOptions...')`.

My function's code is :

```js
async openActionSheet() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CALENDAR, Permissions.REMINDERS);

    if (status === 'granted') {
      Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT)
        .then(calendars => calendars.filter(cal => cal.allowsModifications))
        .then((calendars) => {
          const { showActionSheetWithOptions, navigation } = this.props;
          const options = calendars.map(cal => (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? cal.title : cal.source.name)).concat(['Cancel']);

          const cancelButtonIndex = calendars.length;

          showActionSheetWithOptions({
            title: 'Select a calendar:',
            options,
            cancelButtonIndex,
          },
          (buttonIndex) => {
            const orderId = navigation.getParam('orderId');
            const { orderSet } = navigation.getParam('orderSet');

            const eventConfig = {
              title: `OrderId: ${orderId}` || 'UNKNOWN_NAME',
              startDate: new Date(navigation.getParam('orderDate')),
              endDate: new Date(navigation.getParam('orderDate')),
              location: `${orderSet.location}` || 'UNKNOWN_LOCATION',
              notes: '',
            };

            if (buttonIndex !== cancelButtonIndex) {
              Calendar.createEventAsync(calendars[buttonIndex].id, eventConfig)
                .then(() => Alert.alert('Success', 'Event has been added to your calendar.'))
                .catch(() => {
                  Alert.alert('Error', 'Event was not saved.');
                });
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('ERROR');
          console.log(e);
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Error getting device calendars.');
        });
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'You have to authorize the application to access your calendar.');
    }
  }
```